# Adding ImageView to LinnearLayout dynamically goes wrong

Tags: android, android-layout

I wrote a small function

```
private void addTabIndicators(int tabCount){
    LinearLayout indicatorsContainer = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.indicators_container);
    for(int i = 0; i<tabCount; i++){
        ImageView indicator = (ImageView)this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, null);
        indicatorsContainer.addView(indicator);
    }
}
```

that is supposed to add circles to the linearlayout in my activity based on how many tabs are in the pager adapter. Everything would be cool BUT, the imageviews i add instead of beeing the size declared in the xml layout, are being resized to 1x1px... Any ideas where i could go wrong? Here are the layouts for the indicator and linear layout

tab_indicator.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:src="@drawable/floating_button_background"/>
```

The indicators container:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/indicators_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fault might be here

```
    ImageView indicator = (ImageView)this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, null);
```

You need to pass the root view of your image view to provide the layouts defined in your XML. If you pass null instead, default layoutparams are set.

Place

```
    ImageView indicator = (ImageView)this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, your root view of image view,false);
```

This is a very common mistake. Never pass null except you really know what you are doing.

Read more here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html

Hope it helps

Comment: Great, worked like a charm. Also I found out that if i wanted to use ImageView indicator = (ImageView)this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, null); i had to wrap the imageview into a relativelayout.